# getdate() puede configurarse para la hora de mi pc?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando implementar un reloj en php para mi proyecto, un reloj que contenga la fecha y hora de mi computador, hasta ahora sé algo de cómo trabaja la función getdate() de php y esto es lo que tengo:

```
<?php
  $hoy = getdate();           //contiene todos los datos de fecha y hora

  $dia = $hoy["wday"];        //obtengo número del día actual (0 a 6)
  $dias = ["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"];
  $dia = $dias[$dia];         //capturo el nombre del día

  $ndia = $hoy["mday"];       //el número del día (1 a 31)
  $mes = $hoy["mon"];         //el número del mes (1 a 12)
  $meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre",];
  $mes = $meses[$mes-1];      //capturo el nombre del mes

  $año = $hoy["year"];        //el año (4 dígitos)
  $hora = $hoy["hours"];      //la hora  (esta necesito que sea la de mi pc)
  $minuto = $hoy["minutes"];  //minutos  (estos sí son los de mi pc)

  $ceroh = "";  //cero extra por estética de la hora
  if($hora < 10){
    $ceroh = "0";
  }else{
    $ceroh = "";
  }
  $cerom = ""; //cero extra por estética de los minutos
  if($minuto < 10){
    $cerom = "0";
  }else{
    $cerom = "";
  }

    print_r("<a href='#' id='fechayhora'>"
      .$dia." "
      .$ndia." de "
      .$mes." del "
      .$año.", "
      .$ceroh.$hora.":"
      .$cerom.$minuto
      ." hrs</a>");

?>
```

La salida es la siguiente: Miércoles 2 de Noviembre del 2016, 02:59 hrs

pero el día y la hora están mal pues en este momento es Martes 1 de Noviembre del 2016, 22:59 hrs en mi pc y esa es la hora que quiero que muestre, se puede apreciar que está adelantado 4 horas respecto de la mía, por eso también muestra el día de mañana.

¿Hay alguna forma de quitarle 4 horas a los datos que me entrega getdate()?

**EDIT**

[aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getdate.php) dice que la forma de getdate() es:

array getdate ([ int $timestamp = time() ] )

Y devuelve un array asociativo que contiene la información de la fecha de timestamp, o el momento local actual si no se da timestamp.

Y yo no le estoy pasando ese timestamp, por lo que debería darme la hora local, que es la de mi pc o estoy equivocado?

**EDIT 2**

Cuanto me refiero a obtener la hora de mi pc, es porque en este caso mi pc es el servidor, el objetivo de la pregunta es lograr modificar la hora predeterminada que trae la función getdate(), en este caso quitarle 4 horas. No se hace referencia al uso horario de una ciudad aunque éste sea la manera formal de trabajar con fechas y horas en un servidor.

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje de lado del servidor. Al ejecutar la función `getdate()` obtendrás los detalles del tiempo del servidor donde se ha ejecutado. Según describes, el servidor es la pc donde programas. Entonces, el resultado de `getdate()` va a devolverle la hora actual de tu equipo. Ahora, puede que estés viendo una hora "diferente" pero en realidad debes fijarte también en el valor de la zona horaria: GMT-5, UTC-4, etc. Este valor también es importante, porque a pesar de ser las 8 am en Perú (GMT -5) son las 10 am en Argentina (GMT -3).

Comment: Gracias, finalmente entendí lo de los usos horarios gracias a la respuesta de @rfrp y más abajo la apliqué a mi respuesta, gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He dado con la solución, antes de declarar la variable `$hoy` del código, agrego estas líneas:

```
$timestamp = time() - (60*60*4);
$hoy = getdate($timestamp);
```

Básicamente estoy restando 60 segundos por 60 minutos por 4 horas, lo que se traduce en 14400 segundos, es decir las 4 horas que necesitaba restarle a esa función.

La utilidad de esto es que tendremos un reloj "manual" por así decirlo, modificable solo por nosotros y no por la zona horaria, una opción para países como Chile, donde los gobiernos juegan mucho con la hora. El código final quedaría así:

```
<?php
  $timestamp = time() - (60*60*4);  //capturamos el tiempo -4 horas
  $hoy = getdate($timestamp);       //capturamos los datos de fecha y hora de acuerdo al timestamp recién hecho

  $dia = $hoy["wday"];        //obtengo número del día actual (0 a 6)
  $dias = ["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"];
  $dia = $dias[$dia];         //capturo el nombre del día

  $ndia = $hoy["mday"];       //el número del día (1 a 31)
  $mes = $hoy["mon"];         //el número del mes (1 a 12)
  $meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre",];
  $mes = $meses[$mes-1];      //capturo el nombre del mes

  $año = $hoy["year"];        //el año (4 dígitos)
  $hora = $hoy["hours"];      //la hora  (esta necesito que sea la de mi pc)
  $minuto = $hoy["minutes"];  //minutos  (estos sí son los de mi pc)

  $ceroh = "";  //cero extra por estética de la hora
  if($hora < 10){
    $ceroh = "0";
  }else{
    $ceroh = "";
  }
  $cerom = ""; //cero extra por estética de los minutos
  if($minuto < 10){
    $cerom = "0";
  }else{
    $cerom = "";
  }

    print_r("<a href='#' id='fechayhora'>"
      .$dia." "
      .$ndia." de "
      .$mes." del "
      .$año.", "
      .$ceroh.$hora.":"
      .$cerom.$minuto
      ." hrs</a>");

?>
```

Si se quiere modificar la hora, simplemente tendríamos que reemplazar ese "4" por una variable y luego sumarle o restarle algún valor traído desde una base de datos.

**EDIT**

Esta solución es para cuando queramos modificar la hora por sobre la que ya trae la función time(), lo cual era lo que yo buscaba inicialmente en mi pregunta, pero como decía @rfrp en su respuesta, es necesario tener en cuenta el uso horario de la ciudad en donde estemos, por eso una solución formal sería, ahora para las tres primeras líneas de código:

```
date_default_timezone_set("tu_continente/tu_ciudad"); // ("America/Santiago") por ejemplo
$timestamp = time();
$hoy = getdate($timestamp);    //y desde aquí puedes obtener date y time según tu ciudad
```

Pero esto ya sería apegarse a la zona horaria de manera estándar como muchos sistemas lo hacen, lo cual cambiaría nuestra hora automáticamente y no de forma manual como estábamos buscando en este caso.

Comment: No, el timestamp te da en segundos de UNIX (time epoch)... siempre teniendo como referencia al huso horario que tiene configurado el servidor.

Comment: "No", a qué?
Gracias por la aclaración de todas formas.

Comment: La verdad que restar horas me parece una solución un poco chapucera, deberías comprobar que la hora del servidor está bien configurada, en tu php.ini `date.timezone='America/Santiago'` he puesto la ciudad de tu ejemplo. Si quieres la hora del pc como dice @rfrp tendrías que hacerlo con javascrip

Comment: @blonfu si vivieras en Chile sabrías que muchos sistemas aquí no pueden simplemente guiarse por el uso horario para funcionar correctamente, si fuera así de fácil no estaría buscando una solución tan "chapucera" como dices.

Comment: No se que tiene que ver vivir en Chile, yo puedo configurar mi servidor con la hora de allí y supongo que PHP funciona igual en cualquier país del mundo, ¿no? Ahora mismo me devuelve  la hora 5:20. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: @blonfu lo que dices es algo obvio, en este momento la zona horaria "America/Santiago" está correctamente, pero eso no siempre es así, hay momentos en donde todo se descontrola, atrasan o adelantan la hora cuando se les pega la gana y los dispositivos que usan la zona horaria estándar (todos o casi todos), deben cambiar esa hora "manualmente". Bueno eso es lo que ocurre y es normal que les parezca raro si no son de por acá.
 Mira esto:
http://internacional.elpais.com/internacional/2016/03/14/actualidad/1457974890_661794.html
Si googleas el tema, encontrarás mucho de lo que hablo.

Comment: No sabia todo eso.Vale, en esos casos que se cambia la hora sin previo aviso habría que hacerlo de forma manual pero aún así ¿no es mejor configurar la zona horaria correcta y cambiar la hora solo si es necesario?

Comment: @blonfu exacto, de hecho eso fue lo que hice finalmente, dejé la zona horaria estándar y opcional aumentar o disminuir la hora con esos números simples que usé en esta respuesta, claro que con variables afectadas desde una base de datos con tales horas aumentadas/disminuidas,

Answer (score 0):

Si bien el código que hiciste, de restarle las horas funciona, esa solución no escala. El problema que te está ocurriendo es que estás obteniendo la hora en UTC. Probablemente estás parado en una ciudad con uso horario GMT-4 y de ahí es que tienes 4 horas menos.

Como consejo, considera ajustar las horas según el huso horario de tu ciudad/zona geográfica.

[Sacado de este comentario en la documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.time.php#100220):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo "UTC:".time();
echo "<br>";

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki");
echo "Europe/Helsinki:".time();
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Fíjate que lo que hacen en la rutina es setear el huso horario o ciudad para mostrar la hora.

Ojo, que también tienes un problema en el planteamiento de tu pregunta. Dices que quieres que muestre la hora de tu computador, pero en realidad te está mostrando la hora del servidor que en tu caso coincide con que el servidor es TU PC.
Si quisieras sacar la hora de TU PC, tendrías que hacer alguna rutina en javascript (que es ejecutada localmente).

Comment: Tienes razón en que he planteado mal la pregunta pues siempre me referí a que quiero obtener la hora del servidor, que en mi caso es mi computadora pues uso xampp. Verás, en mi ciudad los usos horarios siempre han funcionado mal, hasta la plataforma de la universidad tiene problemas con eso. Es por eso que no puedo fiarme del huso horario que dices, de lo contrario surgirán los problemas de siempre, mi aplicación debe permitir modificar la hora y con la solución que plantié, es posible, solo basta con guardar en una base de datos las horas aumentadas/disminuidas.

Comment: Como habrás visto, estoy iniciándome en la programación y no veo razones para no "seguir programando".
 
 En cuanto a la escalabilidad de mi solución, no le veo los obstáculos, es una solución simple para cuando no se quiera/pueda usar la zona horaria de algún lugar.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo igual ten en cuenta que lo que estás haciendo es reinventar la rueda. Quizás debieras registrar el timestamp y el huso horario que se estaba ocupando en ese momento, para hacer las conversiones respectivas.
Respecto a que a que no escala, me refiero a que vas a estar TU manejando las horas y no las librerias que ya existen y que probablemente cubren mejor las condiciones de borde que tú. Trata de apegarte a los estandares y evitar problemas.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo respecto a que no funciona bien en tu ciudad y/o universidad no es problema del sistema en si (o quizás sí, ya que alguien manualmente esta controlando la hora). Habitualmente el problema se produce porque: 1.- los gobiernos cambian y no avisan anticipadamente los cambios de hora (en Chile al menos han estado jugando con la hora de verano los ultimos 6 años aprox) 2.- Los sistemas no son actualizados (tzdata) y 3.- los programadores inventan sus propias soluciones :-D

Comment: Exactamente, es el problema que se da en Chile, el cual afectaría bastante mi aplicación, como lo hace con el sistema de mi universidad, por dar un ejemplo. En cualquier caso ¿cuál sería tu solución? - Creo que si nos piden arreglar algo y no podemos hacerlo con los métodos formales que existen, lo único que queda es inventar nosotros una solución eficiente en estos casos.

Answer (score -1):

Y si pruebas así:

```
<?php
    $dias = array ( 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles','Jueves',
                    'Viernes', 'Sabado', 'Domingo' );
    $meses = array ( 'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
            'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre' );
    $dia = intval(date('N')) - 1;
    $mes = intval(date('m')) - 1;

    echo $dias[$dia].' '.date('d').' de '.$meses[$mes].' del '.date('Y, H:i').' hrs';
?>
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, me sigue arrojando datos adelantados por 4 horas respecto a mi PC